# Wildcard in String

Tags: excel, vba, string, function, wildcard

I have a string in a cell, in an Excel spreadsheet which is created via a VBA form.
During the development of the form we have three unique codes (MIC-CT-xxx, MIC-ET-xxx & MIC-UT-xxx).
I have a function that was working. Now I need to search the LastNo based on the last value.

```
Public Function UniqueID()

LastID = xTracker.Range("B" & tRow).Value
LastNo = CLng(Replace(LastID, "MIC-*-", ""))

If Me.CB_CType.Value = "Create" Then
    NewID = "MIC-CT-" & Format(LastNo + 1, "000")

ElseIf Me.CB_CType.Value = "Edit" Then
    NewID = "MIC-ET-" & Format(LastNo + 1, "000")

ElseIf Me.CB_CType.Value = "Update" Then
    NewID = "MIC-UT-" & Format(LastNo + 1, "000")

End If
End Function
```

I could search via an If, but was wondering if there was a method of inserting a wildcard in the text string to find MIC-*-xxx rather than the full string.

Comment: You can use Regex. See: [VBA Regex](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/)

Comment: Unfortunately I’ve not managed to get it to work. might be my limited knowledge of VBA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally managed to find a method that worked. May not be the best method, but works!!

```
Public Function UniqueID()

LastID = xTracker.Range("B" & tRow).Value

Dim Str As String
Str = Left(LastID, 7)

LastNo = CLng(Replace(LastID, Str, ""))

If Me.CB_CType.Value = "Create" Then
NewID = "MIC-CT-" & Format(LastNo + 1, "000")

ElseIf Me.CB_CType.Value = "Edit" Then
NewID = "MIC-ET-" & Format(LastNo + 1, "000")

ElseIf Me.CB_CType.Value = "Update" Then
NewID = "MIC-UT-" & Format(LastNo + 1, "000")

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, i'd suggest to use Regex. The method to return `LastNo` may look like:

```
Private Function GetLastNo(sKey As String) As Long
    Dim pattern As String, sTmp As String
    Dim r As RegExp
    
    On Error GoTo Err_GetLastNo
    
    sTmp = 1
    pattern = "[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{2}-"
    Set r = New RegExp
    r.pattern = pattern
    sTmp = r.Replace(sKey, "")
    
    GetLastNo = CLng(sTmp)
    
Exit_GetLastNo:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Nothing
    Exit Function
    
Err_GetLastNo:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_GetLastNo
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Public Function GetUniqueID(LastID As String) As String
    Dim pre As String, LastNo As Long
    LastNo = GetLastNo(LastID) + 1
    
    Select Case Me.CB_CType.Value
        Case "Create"
            pre = "MIC-CT-"
        Case "Edit"
            pre = "MIC-ET-"
        Case "Update"
            pre = "MIC-UT-"
    End Select

    GetUniqueID = pre & Format(LastNo, "000")

End Function
```

**Note:** Do not forget to add reference to MS VBScript Regular Expression 5.5 library! More at: [VBA Regex](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/)

Good luck!